# How to write a Hibernate query using the WITH clause to customize the ON clause

Tags: sql, hibernate, join, orm, hql

I am using the following HQL query:

```
feeds = (List<Album>) session.createQuery(
                    "select distinct album from Album as album "
                    + "left join album.postImageses as pi with pi.isAlbumCover=:isCover "
                    + "where album.atom.id=:aid ")
                    .setParameter("isCover", "Yes")
                    .setParameter("aid", id)
                    .list();
```

This query is working properly.
But problem is that I want to fetch only Images from`postImageses` whose isAlbumCover value is 'Yes'
but above query is fetching all images(images are album cover or not).

So how can I fetch only images(not other) with `isAlbumCover='Yes'`.
How to resolve this.

Comment: Why do you use a left join?

Comment: for album Image may be ther or not so I think left join in good? Which should I use in your opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate cannot give you partial one-to-many results. You always get all children to ensure consistency.

You need to turn your query up-side down:

```
select ps
from PostImage ps
inner join fetch ps.album albm
inner join fetch albm.atom atm
where ps.isAlbumCover = :isCover and atm.id = :aid
```

This query assumes you have a bi-directional association between an Album and a PostImage, so a PostImage has a @ManyToOne album reference too.

For a proof this is not possible, this is what the [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-joins) says:

> A fetch join does not usually need to assign an alias because the
> associated objects should not be used in the where clause (or any
> other clause).

So the fetch is not affected by where clauses. In your case the *with* clause can at most filter the root entity (Album), but all associated collections (postImageses) will be subject to the [fetching policy](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-the-importance-of-fetch-strategy/).

Because you don't explicitly use a *fetch* directive, it means the query will use the mapping fetch policy. If the one-to-many association is LAZY, it won;t be initialized in this query. Once you access it, Hibernate will issue a new query to initialize it, that's why the *with* clause doesn't filter the children collection.

Comment: The PostImage was using a wrong property so I changed it to: isAlbumCover. Try using left join. Maybe you don't have Atoms for Albums.

Comment: But when there is no isAlbumCover. then it is not fetching album names. eg i have 3 album a1 a2 a3 and only for a1 there is coverimage then it is not giving both 2 album names.

Comment: There should any way to fetch few or specified no of data from collection in joins

Comment: Hibernate can only load full collections, not partial ones. So you either load all images and filter results afterwards, or you select images, but then you won't have the albums without images.

Comment: Then what is need of with clause

Comment: It's needed for left joining nullable to-one associations that need to be filtered if they exist.

Comment: You've just inspired me for a new Hibernate Master Class blog post.

Comment: Really your explanation is great

Comment: But this answer does not meet my criteria

Comment: Check my updated answer to see why it's not possible.