# Map result of query with filtered join back to entity with relation

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to perform an SQL query with a join, where the join has an additional filter condition. Using plain SQL my data is modeled like this:

```sql
create table food_storage (
  name varchar primary key
);
create table food (
  name varchar primary key,
  expired bool,
  stored_in varchar references food_storage(name)
);

insert into food_storage (name) values ('drawer'), ('fridge'), ('cabinet');
insert into food
  (name,        expired, stored_in)
values
  ('teabags',   false,   'drawer'),
  ('beans',     true,    'drawer'),
  ('leftovers', true,    'fridge'),
  ('rice',      false,   'cabinet'),
  ('flour',     false,   'cabinet');
```

And my query looks like this (only selecting a few fields for brevity):

```sql
select food_storage.name, food.name from food_storage
left outer join food on food.stored_in = food_storage.name and not food.expired;
```

| name | name |
| --- | --- |
| drawer | teabags |
| cabinet | rice |
| cabinet | flour |
| fridge | (null) |

However, I am trying to perform this query using JPA, and have the result successfully map back to JPA entities. I modeled my JPA entities like this:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "food_storage")
@Data
public class FoodStorage {
  @Id
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "stored_in")
  private List<Food> foodContents;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "food")
@Data
public class Food {
  @Id
  private String name;

  @Column
  private boolean expired;

  @Column(name = "stored_in")
  private String storedIn;
}
```

For the raw SQL query result above, I need the result to be mapped back into entities like this:

```
[
    FoodStorage(name=drawer, foodContents=[
        Food(name=teabags, expired=false, storedIn=drawer)
    ]),
    FoodStorage(name=fridge, foodContents=[]),
    FoodStorage(name=cabinet, foodContents=[
        Food(name=rice, expired=false, storedIn=cabinet),
        Food(name=flour, expired=false, storedIn=cabinet)
    ])
]
```

I tried using this code:

```java
String sql = """
select food_storage.*, food.* from food_storage
left outer join food on food.stored_in = food_storage.name and not food.expired;
""";
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql, FoodStorage.class);
System.out.println(query.getResultList());
```

But this is the result I get:

```
[
    FoodStorage(name=drawer, foodContents=[
        Food(name=teabags, expired=false, storedIn=drawer),
        Food(name=beans, expired=true, storedIn=drawer)
    ]),
    FoodStorage(name=fridge, foodContents=[
        Food(name=leftovers, expired=true, storedIn=fridge)
    ]),
    FoodStorage(name=cabinet, foodContents=[
        Food(name=rice, expired=false, storedIn=cabinet),
        Food(name=flour, expired=false, storedIn=cabinet)
    ]),
    FoodStorage(name=cabinet, foodContents=[
        Food(name=rice, expired=false, storedIn=cabinet),
        Food(name=flour, expired=false, storedIn=cabinet)
    ])
]
```

Hibernate appears to ignore my manual join, and instead just constructs one `FoodStorage`-instance per result row and subsequently fetches all `Food` per `FoodStorage`. How can I overcome this problem?

I have found Hibernate's `@Where` annotation. Unfortunately for my real-world case the join filter is dynamic, so I cannot use it.

Comment: Do you have to use native queries?

Comment: Please, take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27744226/1854103

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question! If you formulate it as an answer I can accept it and award you the bounty

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use a "fetch join" in JQPL instead of native SQL:

```java
var query = entityManager.createQuery(
        """
        select distinct fs from FoodStorage fs
        join fetch fs.foodContents f
        where f.expired = false
        """, FoodStorage.class);
List<FoodStorage> result = query.getResultList();
System.out.println(result);
```

which results in:

```
[
    FoodStorage(name=cabinet, foodContents=[
        Food(name=rice, expired=false, storedIn=cabinet),
        Food(name=flour, expired=false, storedIn=cabinet)
    ]),
    FoodStorage(name=drawer, foodContents=[
        Food(name=teabags, expired=false, storedIn=drawer)
    ])
]
```

which I believe is because then hibernate is aware of the join's purpose and correctly understands how to map the result back to entities.

But this has a few drawbacks:

- Despite the `left outer join` it fails to fetch `FoodStorage` with zero `Food`. Using `left outer join fetch` instead of just `join fetch` makes no difference.
  As far as I understand that is because the filter condition has to be a regular filter `where f.expired = false`, since JQPL does not support specifying it as a join-condition like `left outer join fetch fs.foodContents f on f.expired = false`.
- It requires a `select distinct`, because otherwise hibernate duplicates the `FoodStorage` entity for each `Food` it contains.
- The limitations of JPQL apply, naturally.

Especially the last point can be a dealbreaker, since I frequently find myself in a situation where JPQL cannot express what I need to express in SQL.

Answer (score -1):

```
String sql = "select distinct food_storage.* from food_storage left outer join food on food.stored_in = food_storage.name and not food.expired; ";
```

The `food.*` is useless.You can use `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true` to print sql. Returning `food.*` does not reduce the number of queries.